# Nested hashmap as key to obtain a value

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a question whose solution I didn't find after google it. The question is I have `hashmap` that contains another `hashmap` as key and against it a single value. I want to get a value for that `hashmap`. For example, there is a following piece of code.

```
HashMap< Hashmap< Integer, String>, Integer> outerHashMap = new HashMap< Hashmap< Integer, String>, Integer>();

Hashmap< Integer, String> innerMap1 = new Hashmap< Integer, String>();

innerMap1.put(100,"A");                                                            

innerMap1.put(101,"B");

innerMap1.put(102,"C");

Hashmap< Integer, String> innerMap2 = new Hashmap< Integer, String>();

innerMap2.put(200,"D");

innerMap2.put(201,"E");

innerMap2.put(202,"F");

outerHashMap.put(innerMap1, 143);

outerHashMap.put(innerMap2, 432);
```

Now my question is, would it be possible to obtain a value for *outerHashMap* by giving a single *key/value* pair for innerMap as a part of key to outerHashMap. Like if I will give just single key/value pair (101, "B") to outerHashMap as a part of key, would I be able to obtain a value 143 ?

Comment: How would you "give a key pair" to `outerHashMap`? It won't magically gain the ability to respond to arbitrary method calls. You could *wrap* the outer `Hashmap` and create a function that takes the key pair, creates a `Hashmap` from them, and uses it to index the composited `outerHashMap`.

Comment: Only by filtering, the method get from Map need a key that is equals to one of its data

Comment: That is my question actually @DaveNewton that would it be possible to obtain a value instead of providing a complete _innerMap_ as a key we just provide a part of _key/value_ pair to _outerHashMap_  ?

Comment: No. No it would not. A `HashMap` is indexed by the **hash** of the key - the entire key. It does not care what the type of the key is, it doesn't even care of the key overrides `hashCode` - it just calls `key.hashCode()` and places the tuple into the right bucket. You seem to assume that a `HashMap` has an ability to introspect the keys and index things differently depending on the type of the key - it does not. In order to retrieve values from your `HashMap` you need to provides a key with an identical `hashCode` and that is `equals` to the key you inserted with. It's that simple.

Comment: P.S. what happens if you insert a two keys that contain an identical entry?

Answer (score -1):

Try make `getOuterValue()` as below, if put in it `outerHashMap`, `innerKey = 101` and `innerValue = "B"` then it returns `outerValue = 143`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<HashMap<Integer, String>, Integer> outerHashMap = new HashMap<HashMap< Integer, String>, Integer>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> innerMap1 = new HashMap< Integer, String>();
    innerMap1.put(100,"A");
    innerMap1.put(101,"B");
    innerMap1.put(102,"C");
    HashMap< Integer, String> innerMap2 = new HashMap< Integer, String>();
    innerMap2.put(200,"D");
    innerMap2.put(201,"E");
    innerMap2.put(202,"F");
    outerHashMap.put(innerMap1, 143);
    outerHashMap.put(innerMap2, 432);
    Integer innerKey = 101;
    String innerValue = "B";
    String outerValue = getOuterValue(outerHashMap, innerKey, innerValue);
}

private static String getOuterValue(HashMap<?,?> hashMapOuter, Integer innerKey, String innerValue) {
    for (Map.Entry entryO : hashMapOuter.entrySet()) {
        HashMap<?,?> keyO = (HashMap) entryO.getKey();
        for (Map.Entry entryI : keyO.entrySet()) {
            Integer keyI = (Integer) entryI.getKey();
            String valueI = (String) entryI.getValue();
            if (keyI.equals(innerKey) && valueI.equals(innerValue)) {
                return String.valueOf(entryO.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    return "No such element";
}
```

Comment: At this point it's not a `Map` anymore, it's just a linear search like any other collection.

Comment: Ok, possibly I didn't understand the @AdnanJaved question.

Comment: Thanks @Grygorii, you have presented one of the solutions that is not best/suitable in my case if data/entries are large enough for _innerMap_. BorisTheSpider is saying right it would not be Map anymore, because we have to traverse first and then can fetch value if exist. While map purpose is to just provide key and get value. And BorisTheSpider I have got you said above that directly as a part of _key/value_ it would not be possible. Thank you  all of you . .